# Project structure, how to create subpackage that will work independently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, git-submodules

Python 3.6+, directory structure:

```
project/
   main.py
   subpackage/
      submain.py
      config.py
```

main.py:

```
from subpackage.submain import attribute1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(attribute1)
```

submain.py:

```
from config import config_param
attribute1 = 1 + config_param
```

config.py:

```
config_param = 100
```

it throws error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/projects/test/project/main.py", line 1, in <module>
from subpackage.subname import attribute1
File "/projects/test/project/subpackage/subname.py", line 1, in <module>
from config import config_param
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

We use couple gitsubmodule in our project and for now it works with:

```
from .config import config_param
```

But I am sure that this is wrong solution because it is already require in some folder/folder/folder to create such relative import ...config or ../../../config.
I already spent a week to find how to do this so that subpackage could work independently(`from config import config_param`), any help, links appreciate, thanks

Answer (score 1):

try to add `__init__.py` files in your dirs https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: not working, unfortunately, no magic this time ;) it was my first attemption to fix this) I  have already read the documentation, also this one https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/

Comment: please vote question, if you also want to see solution, maybe we will catch some python gurus :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution that should work :

- Add `__init__.py` in the subpackage,
- Add the subpackage directory in PYTHONPATH, you can also do it with :
  `sys.path.append(PATH_TO_THE_SUBPACKAGE)` .

The package is now part of the PYTHONPATH, so you can import it like any other libraries with `import config`.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to complete it with a link about how [absolute and relative imports work in python3](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/).

Comment: after this addition you can use ```from config import config_param``` BUT subpackage means it's independent package. And now, try to add `config.py` file to `project` directory with `config_param = 2000`. And run main.py :)

Comment: @FitiavanaRamanandafy please vote question, if you also want to see solution, maybe we will catch some python gurus :)